# Let $f$ be a continuous and positive function on $\mathbb{R}_{+} $ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} <1$

Tags: continuity, functional-equations

Let $f$ be a continuous and positive function on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ such that $\displaystyle\underset{x \to \infty}{\lim} \frac{f(x)}{x} <1$.
Prove the equation $$f(x)=x$$ has at least one solution on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$.

Comment: I think you want $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$

Comment: What do you mean by one solution? It seems like you want to know if the limit of x/x as it goes to infinity is less than 1? Its very clearly 1!

Comment: @C.Falcon i think you might have made some typos resulting in the post being undecipherable. Plus im a little confused by what it seems to say. How does one fix a point?

Comment: I indeed wrote improperly several words. I meant that the question here is to know why there exists a point fixed by $f$. A point $y% is fixed by $f$ if and only if $f(y)=y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f(0)=0$, done. If not $g(x)=f(x)-x, g(0)>0$ and there exists $x>0$ such that $f(x)/x<1$ which implies that $g(x)=f(x)-x<0$, applies IVT at $g$ in $[0,x]$.

Comment: I can't understand your answer !

Comment: What you don't understand?

Comment: If this is correct, why is the counterexample I posted incorrect?

Comment: if $f(x)=x/2,$ then $f(0)=0/2=0$.

Comment: Did not realize $\mathbb{R}_+ := x \geq 0$

Comment: $g(x)=(x)-x$ or $g(x)=f(x)-x$ ?

Comment: thanks I have corrected the typos.

Comment: @Soke his point is if $f(x)= \frac{x}{2}$ then $x=0$ gives a solution for the equation $f(x)=x$

Comment: How you find that there exists $x>0$ such that $f(x)/x<1$ ?

Comment: I use the fact that $lim_{+\infty}f(x)/x<1$ which implies that there exists $N>0$ such that $x>N$ implies that $f(x)/x<1$, this implies that $f(x)<x$ since $x,f(x)>0$.

Comment: @clark I know what his point is. In my head, $\mathbb{R}_+$ is $x > 0$, but the inclusion of zero is what makes it work. I was just saying where my confusion was.